# sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2x}{x^2+(2n+1)^2\pi^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Is there a simple way to prove this equality valid for all $x\in \Bbb R$:

$$\frac1{1+e^x}=\frac12-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2x}{x^2+(2n+1)^2\pi^2}.$$

My idea is to use the uniform convergence of this series on every interval $[a,b]$ and write its general term on an integral form and then interchange $\sum$ and $\int$ but I failed to figure out what integral to use. Any suggestion?

Comment: That is essentially the hyperbolic tangent, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2592376/42969

Comment: The series of the hyperbolic tangent given in the mentioned answer is unknown for me. how can I prove it? @MartinR

Comment: The series for hyperbolic tangent is derived via product $\sin z=z\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-(z^2/n^2\pi^2))$. One can use $\cos z=\sin 2z/(2\sin z) $ to derive product for $\cos z $ and then apply logarithmic differentiation.

Comment: both sides have the same set of residues, so their difference is a bounded and enitre function. This means it is a constant by Liouville's theorem. Set $x=0$ to see the constant is $0$